# Can I achieve this with a NAS?

Tags: windows, backup, network-attached-storage

At my workplace we are like 30 workers. So far they haven't been using backups but now that I'm here this is over! xD However, I've never performed such amount of backups, just local backups from one drive to another.

With a NAS server, can I set up a directory for each user and then install a backup software on each computer to perform backups over the network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on what sort of data you're trying to back-up and how much data there is, but to answer your question - Yes.

If these are just windows clients, and all you want to do is create a backup of the user's profiles and documents libraries, then there are a myriad of solutions that will do what you want, but I think that Window's built in backup tool would be best for you.

Just set up the network storage (This can be a server with a shared drive, or a NAS, it doesn't matter), and configure each client to point to that share to backup their drives. You could even create a home folder on the NAS for each user to restrict access, but without knowing your directory structure (if any) it's hard to make a recommendation for this.

That being said, this would be a good start and will give you time to better research and implement something better. Typically speaking your clients should not be storing data locally on their machines, but rather using centralized, redundant, storage on a company file server, which you will then back-up using a more robust backup strategy.

Comment: For a company of 30 workers, yes centralised storage is certainly a good idea. But, if they aren't even doing backups, best to start somewhere and work towards a centralised system over time. I'm just wary of the OP not doing the backups because of calling them "poor" - poor is 100% better than "none"

Comment: @MarkHenderson Very good point Mark - I might edit the post to reflect that.

Comment: They weren't doing backups because the security policies here are null. I'm new in this company but I managed to step forward and "create" a security analyst role which I assigned to myself, but this is my first job, so still there are things that I have never worked with, like these kind of backups.

Comment: Actuallyyou may get away without backups of desktops easily if you have no fiels stored there. A little sync and fast reinstall from images makes backups of basically static information (os, software) often very superflous. Not the data though ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that. Tons of problems to be expected on the administrative side (machines failing silently unless you realize this). BUt for a low cost solution it is doable, technically.